# OpenShift custom domain sometimes returns 404

Tags: openshift

I have an OpenShift application with custom domain alias, but it's not working sometimes. I followed their instructions for setting an alias, I added a CNAME record at the root of my domain pointing to my .rhcloud.com domain. I use Cloudflare to host my DNS.

It works fine but sometimes it returns error 404. I configured this domain last week so I don't think it's DNS propagation.

Here's the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/paUge.png (sorry I don't have enough rep to post image).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using an A record to point your domain to your openshift gear, we suggest that you use a CNAME to point to your gear in case your gear is migrated to another node

```
cdaley-redhat:~ cdaley$ host www.codingpoop.com
www.codingpoop.com is an alias for codingpoop.com.
codingpoop.com has address 54.224.51.84
codingpoop.com mail is handled by 0 codingpoop.com.
```

You should do the cname for www.codingpoop.com, and then forward the naked domain of codingpoop.com to the cname of www

Comment: I have CNAME pointed to my .rhcloud.com domain, what Cloudflare do is CNAME flattening that's why it looks like an A record. http://imgur.com/BO3Hn6X